# Split string into characters through pipe symbol (Python)

Tags: python, switch-statement

I am trying to check if a character is in "01234589" with the match statement, and my question is,  how can you separate "01234589" into "0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9"?

Here is my code now:

```
match char:
    case DIGITS:
        # Code here
        pass
    case other:
        pass
```

Comment: Do you really need "0"|"1"|"2" or do you want "0|1|2|3"?

Comment: Why use match when you can just use `character in "01234589"`?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it help,

```
>>> s="01234589"
>>> l=[i for i in s]
>>> 
>>> l
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '8', '9']
>>> '5' in l
True
```

Comment: `'5' in s` also works i.e. returns True.